# C# - Chromium - Cef - H264 - MP4 Support

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium, h.264, chromium-embedded

I had tried to built CefSharp using [these](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md) instructions. I had used *update.bat* and *create.bat* files as described [here](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13515&start=40) to enable H264 support. At the end I didn't find any **cef.sln** file at path *c:\code\chromium_git\chromium\src\out\Debug_GN_x86*.

Is there any one who is having these files/dlls mentioned at the end of [this](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13515&start=40) page with the successful H264 codec support so that I can replace and use those files/dlls with my code ?

Or is there any other work around to do so ?

I have to just made a chromium browser with H264 codec support so that I can play videos on the URLs like [this](http://www.html5videoplayer.net/html5video/mp4-h-264-video-test/).

Comment: i'm in the same boat...

Comment: Are you done now ?